# Quarts.net scheduler fails to add jobs SQL table when JobDataMap is added to job during setup

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am running into an issue with scheduling jobs that contain JobMapData. I am using SQL Server to persist job/trigger data.

When I schedule my jobs without adding the JobMapData, they show up in the database as expected, and my application executes the jobs perfectly. When I add the needed JobMapData for the job however, No triggers/Job data gets inserted into the tables.

[My Quartz Config]

```
var schedulerConfig = new NameValueCollection
{
    { "quartz.scheduler.instanceName", "TaskScheduler" },
    { "quartz.scheduler.instanceId", "TaskScheduler" },
    { "quartz.threadPool.type", "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" },
    { "quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "3"},
    { "quartz.threadPool.threadPriority", "Normal" },
    { "quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold", "60000"},
    { "quartz.jobStore.type", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz" },
    { "quartz.jobStore.useProperties", "true" },
    { "quartz.jobStore.dataSource", "default" },
    { "quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix", "_QRTZ_" },
    { "quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateType", "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.SqlServerDelegate, Quartz"},
    { "quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString", "Server=XXXXXXXXXXX; Database=TaskScheduling;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" },
    { "quartz.dataSource.default.provider", "SqlServer" },
    { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary"},
};
```

[Job Setup]

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<SendCyrstalReportJob>()
                    .WithIdentity("SendWorkCenterLoadSummary", "TaskSchedulerService")
                    .WithDescription("Sends the WorkCenterLoadSummary report to a list of email recipients")
                    .UsingJobData("parameters", "MailCrystalReportAsExcel -reportName \\\\fs5\\Reports\\LoadSummary6WeekForecast.rpt -recipients mailrecipient@addy.com")
                    .Build();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                    .WithIdentity("WorkCenterLoadSummaryTrigger", "TaskSchedulerService")
                    .WithCronSchedule("0/10 * * * * ?")
                    .ForJob("SendWorkCenterLoadSummary", "TaskSchedulerService")
                    .UsingJobData("command", "c:\\CommandConsole\\ecc.exe")
                    .Build();

_scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
_scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(_jobListener);
```

The code as provided will result in no job/trigger data being added to the database. If I comment out the UsingJobData from **both** the job definition and the trigger definition will result in the job being scheduled and subsequently executed as expected.

There are no errors thrown, nothing reported to the log files or console window indicating a problem, just no data going to the database.

Any ideas what might be going on? :-)

Comment: It seems that you are using 3.x maybe? You should at least await the commands you are issuing to IScheduler interface. Also such error should show up in logs, can you enable console logging?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After a lot of try/error, I've found this solution:

In your scheduler config change this setting as follows:

```
{ "quartz.jobStore.useProperties", "false" }
```

Put this flag in "false" or just remove it from your config. If you set it to "true", Quartz assumes all your job datamap values will be strings (according to documentation). In my case I was sending integers and strings in the values and this change fixed it. It seems, you're sending strings in the values, but you can give a try changing this setting. 
Source: [Job Stores Documentation](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/job-stores.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change serializer to json

```
from { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary"},
```

to

```
from { "quartz.serializer.type", "json"},
```

and install json serializer for quartz